# Wifi Configuration won't save on a Windows 10 Enterprise PC having UWF filter enabled

Tags: powershell, vbscript, operating-system, windows-10, uwf

I have a machine running on Windows 10 Enterprise edition. The OS has UWF writer protection ON. The network configuration has been applied as per the Microsoft document hosted on the following URL.

[Common Write Filter Exclusions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwfexclusions#networks)

The issue that I am facing is with regards to the WiFi configuration as the WiFi configuration won't persist after system restart. Please suggest if I am missing something here.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not being overwritten by a GPO?

Comment: Not a stackoverflow question.